# SSH certificate path is unknown using Git

Tags: git, ssh

Hi I have generated my SSH certificate using the command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "<<Email Id>>" -b 4096
```

but the RSA key which is getting generated is being placed in the  path

```
/u//.ssh/id_rsa
```

This issue was faced by me initially when for the first time i installed Git Bash. After restart of my system issue was resolved and but again the issue popped now and not able to resolve it even after several restart of the system.

Any body had faced the same issue earlier? Please help me if you know the solution

Comment: Presumably Git for Windows? What is the HOME environment variable set to?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this issue is resolved when i ran Git Bash with Admin Privilege, however still there is an issue when i am trying in normal mode

Answer (score 0):

I once faced this issue, but there was 2 git shell installed on my system...
Make sure, there is only one git bash available on your system.

And re-generate your rsa key as usual

Answer (score 0):

I assume you run mac. You can specify file location with -f flag and either specify location where to save generate key like this:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -C "<<Email Id>>" -b 4096
```

If this does not work try this:

```
ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"  -t rsa -C "<<Email Id>>" -b 4096
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to: `~/.ssh folder`
2. Generate ssh keys: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@example.com" -b 4096`
3. Add it to ssh server by command: `ssh-add your_key_rsa`
4. Copy your_key_rsa.pub to clipboard: `xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/your_key_rsa.pub`
5. Go to github and paste copied key